# Group by with average function in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Hi I am totally new to spark scala.I need an idea or any sample solution.I have a data like this

```
tagid,timestamp,listner,orgid,suborgid,rssi
[4,1496745915,718,4,3,0.30]
[2,1496745915,3878,4,3,0.20]
[4,1496745918,362,4,3,0.60]
[4,1496745913,362,4,3,0.60]
[2,1496745918,362,4,3,0.10]
[3,1496745912,718,4,3,0.05]
[2,1496745918,718,4,3,0.30]
[4,1496745911,1901,4,3,0.60]
[4,1496745912,718,4,3,0.60]
[2,1496745915,362,4,3,0.30]
[2,1496745912,3878,4,3,0.20]
[2,1496745915,1901,4,3,0.30]
[2,1496745910,1901,4,3,0.30]
```

I want to find for each tag and for each listner last 10 seconds timestamp data. Then For the 10 seconds data I need to find average for rssi values.Like this.

```
2,1496745918,718,4,3,0.60
2,1496745917,718,4,3,1.30
2,1496745916,718,4,1,2.20
2,1496745914,718,1,2,3.10
2,1496745911,718,1,2,6.10
4,1496745910,1901,1,2,0.30
4,1496745908,1901,1,2,1.30
..........................
..........................
```

Like this I need to find it. Any solution or suggestions is appreciated. 
NOTE: I am doing with spark scala.

I tried through spark sql query .But not works properly.

```
val filteravg = avg.registerTempTable("avg")
val avgfinal = sqlContext.sql("SELECT tagid,timestamp,listner FROM (SELECT tagid,timestamp,listner,dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY _c6 ORDER BY _c5 ASC) as rank FROM avg) tmp WHERE rank <= 10")
avgfinal.collect.foreach(println)
```

I am trying through array also.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you need last 10 seconds data from current time or maximum of each tag and for each listner ?

Comment: latest 10 seconds data from each tag & listner.From current time or just latest 10 records ..both is fine

Comment: average value for a tag and listner for last 10 seconds will be a single value not multiple values like you have mentioned(0.60, 1.30, 2.20,..), isn't it?

Comment: Yes..It can be single value.

Comment: But incase less than 10 records means, I don't need to find sum.I need to take the existing rssi value

Comment: your output does not match what you really need. for tagid:2 and listner:718 why there are multiple rows?

Comment: Yes for testing purpose I posted this data. Real data is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have a dataframe as

```
+-----+----------+-------+-----+--------+----+
|tagid|timestamp |listner|orgid|suborgid|rssi|
+-----+----------+-------+-----+--------+----+
|4    |1496745915|718    |4    |3       |0.30|
|2    |1496745915|3878   |4    |3       |0.20|
|4    |1496745918|362    |4    |3       |0.60|
|4    |1496745913|362    |4    |3       |0.60|
|2    |1496745918|362    |4    |3       |0.10|
|3    |1496745912|718    |4    |3       |0.05|
|2    |1496745918|718    |4    |3       |0.30|
|4    |1496745911|1901   |4    |3       |0.60|
|4    |1496745912|718    |4    |3       |0.60|
|2    |1496745915|362    |4    |3       |0.30|
|2    |1496745912|3878   |4    |3       |0.20|
|2    |1496745915|1901   |4    |3       |0.30|
|2    |1496745910|1901   |4    |3       |0.30|
+-----+----------+-------+-----+--------+----+
```

Doing the following should work for you

```
  df.withColumn("firstValue", first("timestamp") over Window.orderBy($"timestamp".desc).partitionBy("tagid"))
  .filter($"firstValue".cast("long")-$"timestamp".cast("long") < 10)
  .withColumn("average", avg("rssi") over Window.partitionBy("tagid"))
  .drop("firstValue")
  .show(false)
```

you should have output as

```
+-----+----------+-------+-----+--------+----+-------------------+
|tagid|timestamp |listner|orgid|suborgid|rssi|average            |
+-----+----------+-------+-----+--------+----+-------------------+
|3    |1496745912|718    |4    |3       |0.05|0.05               |
|4    |1496745918|362    |4    |3       |0.60|0.54               |
|4    |1496745915|718    |4    |3       |0.30|0.54               |
|4    |1496745913|362    |4    |3       |0.60|0.54               |
|4    |1496745912|718    |4    |3       |0.60|0.54               |
|4    |1496745911|1901   |4    |3       |0.60|0.54               |
|2    |1496745918|362    |4    |3       |0.10|0.24285714285714288|
|2    |1496745918|718    |4    |3       |0.30|0.24285714285714288|
|2    |1496745915|3878   |4    |3       |0.20|0.24285714285714288|
|2    |1496745915|362    |4    |3       |0.30|0.24285714285714288|
|2    |1496745915|1901   |4    |3       |0.30|0.24285714285714288|
|2    |1496745912|3878   |4    |3       |0.20|0.24285714285714288|
|2    |1496745910|1901   |4    |3       |0.30|0.24285714285714288|
+-----+----------+-------+-----+--------+----+-------------------+
```

Comment: This will show each tag and listner's 10 seconds time stamp data ?? And one more thing... If I have less than 10 records in rssi means I need to use the existing rssi value. No need to sum

Comment: I forgot to change the timestamp to seconds. but the idea is the same. let me see what I can do about it.

Comment: Sure...Thanks for your consideration !

Comment: Incase if I have less than 10 records to sum means I need to take existing rssi value.can you help me for that logic ?

Comment: I didn't understand. Can you clarify?

Comment: humm okay very 10 seconds data..we doing sum.incase If I have less than 10 records means ..we need to take just rssi value.No need to sum

Comment: you mean you don't have to find average if records are less than 10 for each tag?

Comment: Yes exactly. ..I just need to take rssi values only

Comment: Your requirements are increasing for a question. :(

Comment: And one more doubt.Is it possible to do group by in the above data frame ?. I want to do group by with tag and listner .

Comment: Sorry Ramesh. Kindly help in this above scenario please.

Comment: I would need some time :)

Comment: Yeah Sure Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: yeah sure its ramesh.anahcolus@gmail.com

Comment: @Jessijoseph, I have updated my answer. :) and tested it . for the less than 10 records logic, it would be better you ask another question. I will answer that :) if this answer is helpful then please accept the answer and upvote :) it will help me too

Comment: Sure ramesh I will do it

Comment: Can you please check your mail??